# best practices for writing to a file from multiple methods

Tags: language-agnostic, logging

I have a class that contains a bunch of methods for checking data I scrape every week (for things like well-formedness and other errors in gathering the data). Each of these methods performs a test, and then prints out a summary of the test.

I want to print out the output from these tests to a file, but I'm not sure what the best way to do it is. For example...

- Should the class hold an instance variable to the file, and each method open/appends/closes the file? (A problem is that methods sometimes call other methods, so this seems kinda messy?)
- Should each method get passed the file as a parameter? (Seems messy as well.)
- Should each method return a string, and a"central" method that calls all the other tests outputs all these strings to a file?

I'm not really familiar with using logger libraries -- would that be a solution?

### My particular context

I have a scraper that pulls data from various websites and stores them in a database. Websites change all the time, so I'm writing a "scrape checker" program that checks my scrapes for various things, like:

- number of empty results
- length of results
- weird characters in results
- and so on

So I have methods like:

- check_num_empty_results
- check_weird_characters
- check_scrape (calls a bunch of other checks)
- check_scrape_pair (sometimes I want to check pairs of scrapes together, e.g., to match results against each other, so this is different checking each one in isolation)
- etc.

I want my "scrape checker" program to print out a file that summarizes all the checks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separation of concerns. Write code the focuses on the scraping activity and return the value(s) scraped. Then use [aspect oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) for logging, which can simplify the problem greatly as the aspect holds the reference to the file or logging API.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, it depends on what language you're using.

The first solution makes the most sense if your language permits it. For each instance of the logging class, have a field for the file object that you're reading from/writing to. This is basically equivalent to passing the file object as a parameter to every method.

That said, most mature languages have modules that will do a lot of this work for you; off the top of my sh/awk, Perl, and Python all come to mind as being suited to this task (though if you want to, you could use Java or something else).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a logging framework would be a perfect solution for this.  If you are using Java or .NET, log4j and log4net are pretty much the de-facto standards for that.